# I want to align text centre in button but it didn't work when I added height in CSS

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I want to create a card section for my portfolio website with React. Basically it has two buttons in left & right. It will control the scrolling of cards.

When I styling the buttons something is going wrong. I want to align text centre for my text (h1 - tag) in the button but it's not working as I think. When I added height it's messed up like - [with height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HeW2.png) but without height it looks fine - [without height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ia2N6.png).

I added [JSX file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxD9Q.png) and [CSS file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wH1Rx.png) for reference

JSX code

```
import React from 'react'
import './Cards.css';
import Mycard from './Cardshown';
const Cards = () => {
  return (
    <div className='Cardsection'>
        <button className="left-btn"><h1>&lt;</h1></button>
        <button className="right-btn"><h1>&gt;</h1></button>
        
        <div className="cards-container">
            <Mycard cardno='1'/>
            <Mycard cardno='2'/>
            <Mycard cardno='3'/>
            <Mycard cardno='4'/>
            <Mycard cardno='5'/>
            <Mycard cardno='6'/>
            <Mycard cardno='7'/>
            <Mycard cardno='8'/>
            <Mycard cardno='9'/>
            <Mycard cardno='10'/>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}
export default Cards
```

CSS code

```
.Cardsection{
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 3rem 3rem;
    display: flex;
    height: 50vh;
    margin-top: 35rem;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.cards-container{
    padding: 0 10px;
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
.left-btn, .right-btn{
    height: 100%;
    width: 60px;
    position: absolute;
    border: none;
    top: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.left-btn{
    right: 0;
}
.left-btn>h1, .right-btn>h1{
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.436);
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: white;
    width: 50px;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

I am expecting to correct my CSS code that I did wrong & I am unable to catch it so that text in the button goes centre when I added height.

Comment: don't post images of code, I'm not going to type it to try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to vertically center the text in an element.
In general, the proper way to do it is using

```css
  display: flex; /** or `inline-flex`, depending on case **/
  align-items: center;
```

*Note:* if the element has `flex-direction` set to `column`, you have to use `justify-content: center` to align vertically (the flex axes are swapped).

However, in your case, it can also be achieved by setting `line-height`, besides `height`:

```css
  height: 3rem;
  line-height: 3rem;
```

Change `3rem` to whatever you actually want.

Comment: thanks........first suggestion really helps a lot